# Apply jquery and js functions on newly included html fragment

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have set of functions similar to this:

```
$("selector").hide();

$("selector2").on("click", dosomething);

...

// much more here
```

Later after some user interaction, I want to include some new html fragment in the page. This fragment can be short or long and can contain anything (Im not able to predict what is in the fragment).

I would like to apply those jquery/js functions again but only on the new fragment part and not entire page. **How can I do that? (Feel free to use jQuery)**

**EDIT:**

Imagine the selector document.getElementBy..., this selector is working for one document at the time.

Lets assume we already have another 10 elements that passed selector2 and we binded onclick. Now we are adding new fragment of html which might contain new elements passing selector2. What want to do is change document for all jquery methods and then I want to put this new document in the page and let it coexist somehow... not sure if document is good idea.

**EDIT2:**

Page I already have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="js/libs/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function dosomething() {
                alert("My wife hates me!");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="clickable">click me</div>
        <div class="clickable">click me</div>
        <div class="clickable">click me</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Content of `main.js`:

```
$(".clickable").on("click", dosomething);

document.querySelectorAll("div.clickable").style.color = "#333";

// this file is very long and you are forbidden to touch it
```

Now I call ajax from somewhere and I get back some html fragment containing this (or anything else):

```
<div class="clickable">click me too</div>
```

And I want to call:

```
$("body").append(htmlFragment);
```

but first I would like to call main.js on the fragment somehow, but only for fragment and Im forbidden to touch main.js file (maximum is wrapping the content of the file in function);

Comment: You will need to  centralize all the behavior and registration of events in 1 block. You can then invoke this block after the content is added or perhaps periodically.

Comment: You must post minimal code that would replicate your problem as your question is too broad. What are `selector` and `selector2`? Ids? Classes?

Comment: @lshettyl very well, give me a second

Comment: So, in your main.js, you're not allowed to change `$(".clickable").on("click", dosomething);` to something else?

Comment: @lshettyl Yes! I would like to not to change selector `$(".clickable")`. I have thirdparty libraries that are selector dependent. Im not allowed to change it. Problem is, libraries dont know I will add new html on the run...

Comment: Not sure if you were after something like [http://jsfiddle.net/4Lgc3r69/](http://jsfiddle.net/4Lgc3r69/). Let me know.

Comment: @lshettyl I posted my own answer, check it out to see what was my attention. Anyway thx for help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply the same selection as above except within the new fragment then the following will work.

```
$('#newSection selector1').hide();

$("#newSection selector2").on("click", dosomething);
```

Obviously `#newSection` will need to be replaced be the selector of the new fragment.

**Edit**

Based on your comment. You could wrap the relevant jquery in a function and use context selector to apply it to the section.

```
var apply_jQuery = function(context){

    // Add all relevant jQuery that needs to be reapplied here. eg
    $('selector', context).click(/*do something*/);

}

apply_jQuery($(document)); // Will apply to full document.

var newFragment = $('#newFragment');
apply_jQuery(newFragment); // Will apply to fragment only.
```

Comment: thx but lets assume we have 5k LOC javascript and Im not able to augument all selectors I already have. It is like very well known function `live` except this must not be applied only for event bindings but every single function. Perhaps document substitution is the best idea, but I dont know how to do that properly...

Comment: Just made an edit. I think it could do what you want if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, you can just wrap your newly added fragment in some container, then choose it with jQuery and apply the functions, like this:

```
$('.container').hide();
```

It's rather trivial though... Probably you have something more complicated or just different there and you didn't mention this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to bind an event to dynamically generated elements. In your case those elements have a class called "clickable"

If this is what you want to achieve then use the following code

```
$('body').on("click",".clickable", function(){
    //do something...
})
```

The above code binds an event to the any element that has the class clickable which is contained in the body even if it is dynamically generated after this script is called and you do not need to call your main.js file again.

Answer (score 0):

First I was thinking about [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment/DocumentFragment), but the technology is still experimental.

Then I did this nasty trick, Im not sure about its performance. First I detach all elements from body (or wrapper), then I append new html fragment. After calling main function again, selectors are able to find only present elements and event bindings are not replicated to standing elements. Then I detach this fragment again and put origin html back. It works for both, jquery and native selectors.

It is not the best solution, but simple and only one I found. Perhaps someone will find something better.

```js
// function that applies js only for new html
function reaplyJS(newHtmlFragment) {
  var tempContent = $("#wrapper").children();
  tempContent.detach();
  $("#wrapper").append(newHtmlFragment);
  main();
  newHtmlFragment.detach();
  $("#wrapper").append(tempContent);
}


// this is test part
function appendNewClickable() {
  var htmlFragment = $('<div class="clickable">click me</div>');
  reaplyJS(htmlFragment);
  $("#wrapper").append(htmlFragment);
}

var click = 0;

function writeConsoleMessage() {
  click++;
  console.log("click number: " + click);
}


function main() {
  $(".append").on("click", appendNewClickable);


  $(".clickable").on("click", writeConsoleMessage);

  var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("div.clickable");
  for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i].style.color = "#FF3232";
  }
}

$(main);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="append">append new clickable element</div>
  <div class="clickable">click me</div>
  <div class="clickable">click me</div>
  <div class="clickable">click me</div>
</div>
```